# Show that all solutions of $z^5 - z + 16 = 0$ satisfy $1 \lt |z| \lt 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, quintics

I have to show that all solutions of $z^5 - z + 16 = 0$ satisfy $1 \lt |z| \lt 2$.

My attempt: By using Euler's formula I can rewrite the equation into $r^5e^{5i\phi} - re^{i\phi} = -16$ and then rewrite this into $$r^5 \cos(5\phi) - r \cos(\phi) + i(r^5 \sin(5\phi) -r \sin(\phi)) = -16 + i0 $$

so I get

1. $r^5 \cos(5\phi) - r \cos(\phi) = -16$
2. $r^5 \sin(5\phi) -r \sin(\phi) = 0$ which becomes $r^4 \sin(5\phi) = \sin(\phi)$

Here I don't know how to proceed. Any tips?

Comment: Usually this kind of exercise can be done with [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thanks for the remark! I found it in my script! Somehow I ovrelooked it :)
I understand the following part: analogous to the example from  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem at the section "Usage", I have a function $f(z) = z^5$ which grows faster then $g(z) = -z + 16$. So. on the disk $|z| \lt 2$, we have the zeroes of $z^5$ since $|-z+16| \leq 14 \lt 32 = |z^5| $ for every $z = 2$. But how do I show that it is bounded from below, i.e. $1 \lt |z|$ ?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut hmmm sorry but I'm not sure how to apply it

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut can I do it maybe like this:
Let $f(z) = z^5$ and $g(z) = -z + 16$. On the disk $|z| \lt 1$ we have: 
$|- z + 16| \leq 15 \lt 1^5 = 1 = |z^5|$ which is a contradiction. So we get that $|z| > 1$. And combined with  the result above, we have $1 \lt |z| \lt 2$. Would this be correct?

Comment: Try $f=16$. Then $g=z^5-z$ and $|g|\le|z^5|+|z|=2<16=|f|$. With $f=z^5$ it won't work as it would mean there are $5$ roots (the number of roots of $z^5$) inside the unit circle, and you want to prove there are none (that's why I picked a constant polynomial: no roots).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut but doesn't the fact that I showed the contradiction means that $f = z^5$ with $|z| \lt 1$ can't have the roots inside the disk?

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't see the contradiction here (but you write $15<1$, which is wrong). But indeed, you can write that $|-z+16|>15$ and $|z^5|<1$, and you can't have a root. It works as well.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes, this is exactly the contradiction. Because at first, we assume (according to Rouche's theorem), that $|g(z)| \lt |f(z)|$. So, for $|g(z)| = |-z+16|$ and $|f(z)| = |z|^5$ and $|z| \lt 1$, we have: $|-z + 16| \leq 15 \lt 1^5 = 1$. So, $15 < 1$ doesn't hold and from this follows that, for $|z| \lt 1$, $|g(z)| \lt |f(z)|$ doesn't hold.

Comment: Rouché only tells you that **if** you can find $f$ and $g$ that satisfy some condition, $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of roots. If you can't it says nothing. I.e. you don't *assume* something on $f$ and $g$, either you have them and you can apply the theorem, or you haven't and you have try by other means. A contradiction in the hypotheses of a theorem only tells you that you can't apply the theorem, and it tells nothing about the truthness or not of the conclusion of the theorem.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification! Perhaps I didn't correctly understood the theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|z^5-z|=|-16|=16.$

If $|z|=2$ then $|z^5-z|\ge |z^5|-|z|=|z|^5-2=30>16.$

If $|z|>2$ then $|z-1|\ge |z|-|1|>1$ and $|z|^4>0,$ so $|z^5-z|=|z|^4\cdot |z-1|> |z|^4\cdot 1  > 2^4=16.$

If $|z|\le 1$ then $|z^5-z|\le |z^5|+|z|=|z|^5+|z|\le 1^5+1=2<16.$

Comment: In my last line I actually got "1+1=2" into a proof.

Answer (score 2):

You get $|z| = \dfrac{16}{|z^4-1|}.$ If $|z|\leq1,$ then you have $16\leq|z^4-1|<|z|^4 +1 < 2,$ which is absurd. If $|z|\geq 2,$ then $8\geq |z^4-1|\geq||z|^4-1|\geq 15,$ which is also absurd. Looks like, this bound is not that tight.

Comment: shouldn't it be $-16$ ?

Comment: oh, You took the absolute value for the LHS and RHS, right?

Comment: This is a very nice solution without using high level theorems like Rouché's theorem.